# Sonata Admin search feature : The Request object has not been set

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, sonata

I want to activate the sonata admin search feature after the migration to of symfony to version 3.4.2.
I found a problem in sonata block service:

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("The
>   Request object has not been set").

this is sonata block configuration :

sonata_block.yml

```
sonata_block:
    default_contexts: [cms]
    blocks:
        sonata.admin.block.admin_list:
            contexts:   [admin]
        sonata.admin.block.search_result:
            contexts: [admin]
        sonata.block.service.text:
        sonata.block.service.rss:
```

any solution please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to override the get request function because she throws an exception:

```
  public function getRequest()
    {
        if (!$this->request) {
            throw new \RuntimeException('The Request object has not been set');
        }

        return $this->request;
    }
```

so I create a class that extends the abstract admin and make every class in my admin folder extends from it:

```
class MYAdmin extends AbstractAdmin
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getRequest()
    {
        if (!$this->request) {
            return $this->request = $this->getConfigurationPool()->getContainer()->get('request_stack')->getCurrentRequest();
        }
        return $this->request;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using SonataTranslationsBundle? this was [fixed recently](https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataTranslationBundle/pull/185). Maybe you should update? If not please open an issue and provide a stack trace.

Comment: I tried this solution but in vain, the problem is in sonata.admin.block.search_result

Comment: @MohammadTrabelsi can you give me here full stack trace of the exception or open an Issue on github

Comment: the full stack is too big : this is the short version : Twig_Error_Runtime:
An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("The Request object has not been set").

  at vendor/sonata-project/admin-bundle/src/Resources/views/Core/search.html.twig:39

Comment: I opned an Issue : this is the link :https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle/issues/4966